# Cypress and setting variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to set a variable in a each loop in cypress, and use the variable later. the variable increments in the loop, but becomes zero outside of it when I use it. Can you explain to me why, and how I can correct this? Thanks

```
public getNoEntries(fullName: string) : number
  {
    let noEntries: number = 0;
    cy.get(this.employeeList).find('li').each((x) =>
      {  
        var entryName = x.text().trim();
        if (entryName.localeCompare(fullName)==0)
        { 
          ++noEntries;
          cy.log("in loop: "+noEntries.toString());                       
        }             
      });

    cy.log('out of loop:'+noEntries);

    return noEntries;
  }
```

The output is:

in loop: 1
in loop: 2
in loop: 3
out of loop: 0

I want it to return 3. How can I do this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As explained very well in [cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values),

> You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

So instead of using the function's return value, you may however chain your getNoEntries() functions code inside the calling functions cypress command itself.

Also 'outofloop' is 0 because the scope of variable new value ended in the cy.get() itself. To achieve the new value of the variable, you can chain the second log() in then() of first command as below..

```
let noEntries: number = 0;
cy.get(this.employeeList).find('li').each((x) =>
  {  
    var entryName = x.text().trim();
    if (entryName.localeCompare(fullName)==0)
    { 
      ++noEntries;
      cy.log("in loop: "+noEntries.toString());                       
    }             
  })
  .then(()=>{
    cy.log('out of loop:'+noEntries);
  })
```